# Почему не добавляются записи Yii2

Tags: yii2, activerecord

Есть модель

```
<?php
namespace common\models\accounts;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{

public $password;
public $password_repeat;
public $rememberMe;
public $school;
public $email;
public $userType;

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'user';
}

public function rules(){
    return [
        [['email', 'password', 'password_repeat', 'school', 'userType'], 'required', 'message'=>'объязательно к заполнению'],
        ['email', 'unique', 'message'=>'Этот email уже используется']
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'email' => 'Email',
        'password' => 'Пароль',
        'password_repeat' => 'Повторите пароль',
        'school' => 'Школа',
        'userType' => 'Тип пользователя'
    ];
}

/**
 * Finds an identity by the given ID.
 *
 * @param string|integer $id the ID to be looked for
 * @return IdentityInterface|null the identity object that matches the given ID.
 */
public static function findIdentity($id)
{
    return static::findOne($id);
}

/**
 * Finds an identity by the given token.
 *
 * @param string $token the token to be looked for
 * @return IdentityInterface|null the identity object that matches the given token.
 */
public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    return static::findOne(['access_token' => $token]);
}

/**
 * @return int|string current user ID
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return string current user auth key
 */
public function getAuthKey()
{
    return $this->auth_key;
}

/**
 * @param string $authKey
 * @return boolean if auth key is valid for current user
 */
public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
{
    return $this->getAuthKey() === $authKey;
}

public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        if ($this->isNewRecord) {
            $this->auth_key = \Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

static public function getUserType()
{
    return [
        -1 => 'Не проверен',
        0 => 'admin',
        1 => 'Директор',
        2 => 'Завуч',
        3 => 'Методист',
        4 => 'Тренер',
        5 => 'Спортсмен',
        6 => 'Опекун'
    ];
}

static public function getUserTypeForPublic($exclude = false)
{
    $userTypes = self::getUserType();
    $newUserType = array();
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++)
    {
        $newUserType[$i] = $userTypes[$i];
    }

    return $newUserType;
}

public function sign(){
    $user=new User();
    $user->email=$this->email;
    $user->school=$this->school;
    $user->userType=$this->userType;
    $user->password=$this->password;
    if ($user->save()){
        return true;
    } else {
        var_dump($user->save());
    }
}
}
```

Данные передаются, но после вызова ***save()*** не сохраняются. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: скорее всего в публичных свойствах, уберите их

Comment: если я их уберу - мне выдает такое сообщение: `Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Setting unknown property: common\models\accounts\User::school`

Comment: и так каждое свойство

Comment: ну всё правильно, в `public function sign(){...  $user->email=$this->email; ...}` AR как должен определить, какое свойство является виртуальным а какое реальным полем в БД, если их имена одинаковы?

Comment: не совсем вас понял? можете как то на примере показать?

Comment: либо создавайте отдельный класс, где собираете объект наследуясь от Model, либо уберите публичные свойства, а модель юзера собирайте и сохраняйте в контроллере

Comment: в общем публичные свойства добавлять в класс, наследуемый от ActiveRecord никто не запрещает, но их имена не должны совпадать с именами столбцов в БД

Comment: спасибо, сделал отдельную модель - и все заработало. но! одно свойство все таки не сохраняется. как мне понять почему? куда копать?

Comment: нет, не обозначено

Answer (score 0):

Наличие ошибок можно так проверить.

```
if (!$user->save()){
    var_dump($user->getErrors());
}
```

И в моделе на всякий случай убедиться что процесс дошел до Save

```
public function beforeSave($insert) {
    if (parent::beforeSave($insert)) {
        if ($this->isNewRecord) {
            $this->auth_key = \Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString();
        }

        return true;
    }

    echo('BeforeSave');
    return false;
}
```